# Correct glmer distribution family and link for a continuous zero-inflated data set

Tags: r, continuous-data, lme4-nlme, zero-inflation

[image]

Data set details:

- Zeros are "real" (volume)
- Data set is heavily left skewed (even when zeros are excluded)
- Response is continuous (volume)

Can anyone recommend a distribution family and link that I can use for glmer?

Alternatively, can assumptions of normality be ignored in this case (if I'm using lmer)?

[image: Here is a histogram of the residuals from lmer(vol ~ status + (1|id), data=c) for species c]

[image: and for species m]

Comment: residuals are from: lmer(vol ~ status + (1|id), data=data)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that you are describing conditional and not marginal distributions (i.e., if your response variable is `y` then `hist(mydata$y)` will *not* typically give you what you want; you should be concerned with the distribution *around* the expected values):

- Changing the link function won't help you; it determines the dependence of location on predictors, not the conditional distribution
- I would recommend a two-stage approach; use a binomial model to fit zero vs. non-zero, then use either a Gamma model (probably with a log link, it's much more stable than the canonical inverse link) or (more flexibly) transform your non-zero values to make them approximately Normal.
- There are very few distributional models for positive data that admit zeros (Gamma, Weibull, log-Normal all give likelihood=zero for data exactly equal to zero, at least for some parameter regimes [LN always, Gamma and Weibull for shape<1]; in any case they don't account for a point mass (spike) at zero.
- Similarly, some data transformations (Box-Cox) will break with non-positive data, others (Yeo-Johnson) won't break, but won't handle a pile of zeros gracefully.
- The only real downside of the two-stage model is that the zero-vs-nonzero and conditional-if-nonzero models are completely independent.
- If you want to stick with the Gaussian assumption, you could do something nonparametric (bootstrapping or permutation tests) to try to make your results robust to violations of distributional assumptions.
- You could try a model based on a [Tweedie distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tweedie_distribution); check out the [cpglmm function](http://finzi.psych.upenn.edu/R/library/cplm/html/cpglmm.html) from the `cplm` package.

Comment: I'm trying to avoid breaking it up into two analyses if I can.

Comment: My residuals are not normal either.  They look like negative binomial distributions...

Comment: A negative binomial probably (almost certainly) doesn't make sense for a continuously distributed response.  Probably need to see some pictures before we can say anything else.

Comment: Ben, that's what I thought.  I am having a hard time tracking down an equivalent distribution for continuous data

Comment: So, for "part two of the analysis, I've tried: glmer.1<-glmer(non_zero_vol ~ status + (1|id), data=data, family=Gamma(link = "log"));   lmer.1 <- lmer(non_zero_vol ~ status + (1|id), data=data);   and glmer.2<-glmer(non_zero_vol ~ status + (1|id), data=data, family=Gamma(link = "inverse")).

Comment: AIC values are: glmer.1: 7.4, glmer.2: 16.1, lmer.1: 27.47.  The residuals of lmer.1 are not normal. There are some high values [real] in the data, which seem to be pushing the residuals off from normality. Shapiro wilk: W = 0.9153, p-value = 0.01776. I've included a histogram of the lmer.1 residuals above.  I'm not sure if I should transform the data and use lmer, or try another family in glmer.

Comment: Any chance you can post data somewhere?  Is status categorical/factor?  Assuming so, the link function is only controlling for heteroscedasticity among status groups (i.e., since there are no continuous input variables and no interactions, the predictor is *necessarily* linear with respect to the input variables).  I would probably try `MASS::boxcox(lm(non_zero_vol~status,data=data))` (i.e. ignore the random effect for the moment) and transform ...