# Two-part models in R: continuous outcome with too many zeros

Tags: r, regression, poisson-regression, truncation, tobit-regression

I am estimating a model where the outcome variable is continuous, more specifically a percentage in the form of a 0 to 1 range. This variable has one potential problem: many of its cases equal zero (around 40%). Since it is not a count variable, I cannot employ a Poisson zero-inflated model. I have been searching for the appropriate technique to handle the problem, and found out that probably the most indicated would be the so called two-part model estimation - which is pretty much the joint application of a logit and a truncated estimation.

However, I would like to check with you all:

1. If there are also other options when we do have a continuous / percentage outcome variable that is zero-inflated.
2. How can I run a two-part model in R? I've found a few suggestions online, like the hurdle package. But none actually seem to work with continuous outcomes.

Comment: I'd normally suggest a log-transformation, but you can't do log of 0. You could try turning all of your 0s to really really small decimals and logging the data; that may normalize it. But it sounds like your hypothesis is there may be a separate process defining the 0s from the greater than 0s - that is one of the motivations for doing a 2 part model, not just the 0 inflation. Also, keep in mind your DV is a percentage, bounded by definition between 0 and 1, so a linear regression may give you impossible predicted values.

Comment: What is your outcome variable measuring? Percent of what?

Comment: Is your data a mixture of count data with some sort of weights applied, and the zeros are examples when the count equal zero?  What is your intuition for _why_ there are so many zeros?  The answer will depend on this.  Zero inflated Poisson is just a mixture model, so the same idea can be applied to non count data.

Comment: Thanks for your quick responses. In fact, I suspect there is separate process leading to the 0 and to the probability function of from above zero to 1. One affects the reason for why a company is/isn't present in a district; the second affects the degree of market share in each district. My outcome variable is not a mixture of count data, it is a percentage. It measures market share in districts. Any suggestions about any R implementation?

Comment: If you suspect different processes, then I would suggest a two-part model (similar to the hurdle model for count data). First estimate a standard binary regression for zero vs greater. Second, estimate a regression model (e.g., a beta regression) only for the values in (0, 1).

Comment: As I answered [here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/142013/correct-glmer-distribution-family-and-link-for-a-continuous-zero-inflated-data-s/142021#142021), a Tweedie distribution is another possibility. As an R implementation, I would fit a binomial or binomial mixed model with (share>0) as a response variable, then a Gamma or a log-Normal (possibly mixed) model to the non-zero data only.